# Ruby backend doesn't work on heroku live site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, production, heroku-postgres

On production, only my site's static pages work, and all pages with instance variables return a 404 error. For some reason, when I run `heroku logs`, the error does not appear in the log. Everything is fine locally.

I am not sure where this issue might originate from, so please ask in the comments!

Thanks,

Jill

Edit:

Here's the routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :comps do
    resources :tracks do
      member { get :download }
    end
  end

  devise_for :users
  resources :shows
  resources :contacts, only: [:index, :new, :create]

  get 'literal/noise' => 'literal#noise'

  root 'welcome#hi'

end
```

Comment: Can you show us your routes? have you upped the debug-level on heroku so you get more in the logs? Can you try that, then try looking in the logs again? :)

Comment: Thanks for your response @TarynEast. I just updated my question to include my routes file. I'm not sure what you mean by "upped the debug-level," could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: In the config file for each environment you will have a debug-level (which guides how verbose the logging is for that environment). For development this is usually something like `:debug` but production often has the logs quietened to `:info` or `:error`... which means for fewer logs. Search for `debug_level` in each of your config files and you'll find it and can change the one for production to be the same as for development (at least in these early stages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I never ran `heroku run rake db:migrate`, so heroku was look for instances of models that didn't exist yet :{